# MediaPlayer consuming CPU randomly [UWP] [UI.Composition]

Tags: uwp, composition

Simple app that changes video.

While running in diagnostic tool CPU rises and holds about 50% (task manager 5%) until stop, another run it remains at 5% (task manager less than 1%).

Code is the same all the time. Videos are of the same format.

In Performance Profiler i see that nvwgf2umx.dll (nvidia) 100% is in use calling WaitForSingleObjectEx and ReleaseSemaphore.

Why each random run i get two variants of CPU consumption?

```
    private void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _playlist = new MediaPlaybackList();
        foreach (var uri in _uris)
        {
            _playlist.Items.Add(new MediaPlaybackItem(MediaSource.CreateFromUri(uri)));
        }

        _mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer
        {
            IsLoopingEnabled = true,
            AutoPlay = false,
            IsMuted = true,
            Source = _playlist,
        };
        _mediaPlayer.SetSurfaceSize(new Size(512, 512));

        _visual = ElementCompositionPreview.GetElementVisual(this);
        _compositor = _visual.Compositor;

        _surfaceVideoBrush = _compositor.CreateSurfaceBrush(_mediaPlayer.GetSurface(_compositor).CompositionSurface);
        _surfaceVideoBrush.Stretch = CompositionStretch.UniformToFill;

        _spriteVisualVideo = _compositor.CreateSpriteVisual();
        _spriteVisualVideo.Size = new Vector2(512, 512);
        _spriteVisualVideo.Brush = _surfaceVideoBrush;

        ElementCompositionPreview.SetElementChildVisual(Grid, _spriteVisualVideo);

        _timer.Tick += _timer_Tick;
        _timer.Start();
    }

    private void _timer_Tick(object sender, object e)
    {
        _timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(Random.Next(200, 2000));
        NextVideo();
    }

    private void NextVideo()
    {
        _mediaPlayer.Pause();
        _playlist.MoveTo((uint)Random.Next(0, 15));
        _mediaPlayer.Play();
    }
```

XAML has only 1 Grid

PC - i7 4770, nVidia GTX9700

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a bug in Visual Studio 2015. If i open this project and run the code - CPU goes up. If i switch to designer view in Visual Studio while running the code and wait it's loaded - CPU falls back and everything's OK.